# Procexp.exe top line in threads tab won't stay highlighted

Tags: process-explorer

I am having an issue with using procexp.exe. When viewing the 'Threads' tab, and sorting by CPU usage, the list of threads updates so quickly that it is nearly impossible for me to get a stack trace on the thread with the most CPU usage. What ever thread I highlighted usually is not at the top of the list anymore by the time I can click the 'Stack' button. Is there a way to keep the top line highlighted at all times regardless of what thread is there? Or, does anyone know of a better application to use for Windows 32/64-bit processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. keep window with 'Threads' tab open
2. switch to main **procexp** window
3. from main menu select **View** > **Update Speed** > **Pause**  (or **10 seconds**)

The top line in process properties is now static or has 10 seconds refresh interval.

Another way:

Even if you have fastest update speed selected (0.5 seconds), you should be able to

1. sort thread list by CPU Usage descending (by clicking column header)
2. ensure that thread list has focus (click inside)
3. press `Home` key (first record gets selected)
4. press `Alt+S` what is equivalent to pressing `Stack` button

normally you should be able to press `Home` followed by `Alt+S` even within short refresh period